# Creating a stop motion vieo?

Tags: youtube, stop-motion

I love this short 15 second video. I'm a beginner (have mercy), but how did they do this?

Comment: I don't see a link and I don't see any edit indicator. ??

Comment: Mulvya, there is a youtube video in my post above. Do you not see it?

Comment: No. On checking source, I see that it is a Flash object. I have Flashblock on and I usually get a button indicating disabled flash objects. No such thing here. Anyway, I see the link in the source. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One frame at a time. Many film cameras (as opposed to video cameras) will allow the creator to shoot a single frame of film. The camera is set up on a tripod, pointing at countertop with the Quest Bar, strawberries, and peanuts on it. The filmmaker shoots one frame of film. Then he/she moves the Quest Bar a couple millimeters to the right. Then shoots another frame. Moves the Quest Bar a couple more millimeters. Shoots another frame. And so on, until the Quest Bar is in the middle of the shot. Then he/she opens the end of the wrapper a bit, and shoots another frame of film. Opens the wrapper a little more, shoots another frame. Slides the wrapper a couple millimeters to the left, shoots another frame.  And so on.

This is standard "clay animation" or "Claymation". [You can read more about it here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clay_animation)

Comment: Brett, that must be a lot of work right? How many frames do you think it would have taken them to do this?

Comment: It is a LOT of work! I've done some myself.  Remember that film has 24 frames every second.  So for 18 seconds (like this video), that's over 400 separate positions and shots!

Comment: Holy moly. Not accounting the shots they probably had to retake right?

Comment: Exactly! And this is the same technique done for ENTIRE FILMS sometimes, such as The Box Trolls, Chicken Run and The Nightmare Before Christmas. Sometimes to make the process a little bit faster, they will shoot 2 frames of each setup. But that makes the final film look more jumpy. (BTW, thank you for marking my answer as "correct"!)

Comment: You're welcome Brett. Thank you as well for that. One more thing, when we see the gal's hand putting the cookies (quest bar) in the oven, is that stop motion, or could it be an effect you could apply to it? It doesn't seem as stop motion as in the beginning.

Comment: To me, her hand (which appears several times!) looks a bit jerky, like it's stop-motion animated too. That is actually simpler and quicker to shoot: the actress holds the tray, and moves it forward 1 cm. The camera operator shoots one frame of film. The actress moves her hand forward 1 cm more. The camera operator shoots one frame of film. And so on. I think that's simpler than the rest of the shoot because the actress doesn't have to get her hand out of the shot before shooting the next frame.

Answer (score 1):

The most basic principal of stop motion is taking pictures of still objects,moving them slightly for each frame, then playing them very quickly to give the illusion of movement. For example, when the bar came out of the package the animator started with a frame of the closed package. Than they opened the end of the package then they took another frame(picture).They moved the package off the bar sightly and took another picture. They slowly did this until the bar was all the way out of the package. It's not that hard, really. Give it a try!